# Filter the JSON content using Angular 2/Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a JSON response which is getting from server. And i want to show only the '**virtualAddr**' key value in selectbox.  can any one suggest how do i filter the items using Angular 2/Ionic 2?

```
this.beniObj = [
        {      
          "nickName": "Pavans",
          "type": "IFSC",
          "accountNo": "002010172035" 
        },
        {         
          "nickName": "Pavand",
          "type": "VPA",
          "virtualAddr": "Maneesha@ndicate"
        }
      ]
```

### template code

I tried in the following way, but i am getting the blank value for first  item.

```
 <ion-select [formControl]="beneficiaryvid">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let vaddrlist of beniObj" [value]="vaddrlist.virtualAddr">{{vaddrlist.virtualAddr}}</ion-option>
              </ion-select>
```

Comment: the first item in the array doesnt have a ``virtualAddr`` attribute .

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using filter.

```
 public filteredItems(fitems, type){
        return fitems.filter(page => {
          return page.hasOwnProperty(type);
        });
      }

 this.filteredItems(data.content, "virtualAddr");
```